# How to switch to FileBrowser side pannel on OS X?

Tags: macos, plugins, sublimetext3, shortcut

I installed [SublimeFileBrowser](https://github.com/aziz/SublimeFileBrowser) plugin on SublimeText3 but I am not able to find a way to move, with a keyboard shortcut, from the code pannel to the SublimeFileBrowser panel. All the time I have to click on the destination panel and, from there, move with the keyboard.

Could someone please help me?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is just a view as everything else and you can use your usual group navigation. I.e. `ctrl+1`, `ctrl+2`, ... to focus groups by numbers and `ctrl+k, ctrl+left`/`ctrl+k, ctrl+left` to focus neighboring groups.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the @r-stein comment, I tried again (for some reason, it did not work the first time I tried) and using `ctrl+<number>` moved my cursor to the corresponding panel.

On the other hand, on OS X, you should use `⌘+k,⌘+left` and `⌘+k,⌘+right` to move to the left or to the right panel, respectively.